# Run FileObserver inside JobIntentService

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, fileobserver, android-8.1-oreo, jobintentservice

My app runs a `FileObserver` inside a service (the service runs 10 minutes after a temp file is created, and it observes the file for 60 seconds in order to delete it if it's not used).

Due to Android 8 restrictions, I cannot start a service from background. AFAIK alternatives are:

1. Running a foreground service (but I don't want to show a notification icon)
2. Use `JobService` (but it's only available since API 21)
3. Use `JobIntentService`

`JobIntentService` runs `onHandleWork` on a background thread, and upon returning, the work will be considered complete. So, the question is:

How can I wait until `FileObserver` finishes? Is it ok to use something like `while(!fileObserverFinished) Thread.sleep(100);`? Is there a better way?